# Cannot open Office file types directly from server

Tags: office-integration, ssl

I have a big problem, in my Sharepoint site when I am trying to open Excel files in document library, it shows `" access the web server by default disabled. It uses basic authentication but it does not use Secure socket layer(SSL)"` error.

I'm running Basic authentication over a non-SSL connection in Sharepoint.

Comment: thanks for your response. already i installed .msi( from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2123563), but it asking the credentials every time. my client don't want this process. Thanks,
Bommula

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the site to the Trusted Sites or Intranet Sites, via the Internet Explorer Options.

Comment: Thanks Marius for your response , Already i tested the site by adding in Intranet sites and trusted sites via internet explorer options, but no result. i think the problem with SSL certificates. please help me if you have any idea about SSL certificates. Thanks,
Bommula.

Answer (score 0):

There is a MS KB regarding to this error : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2123563